# Xcode: Direct Xcode to use config files for build settings

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

I am working on a new project and I need to define the build settings for the debug and release targets. For that purpose, I want to create configuration files so that Xcode can pick relevant settings from the file itself and populate the `Build Settings`. This helps in easier maintenance of the code.

Currently, no settings are being picked from the config files. How can I make sure that Xcode performs the desired function?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to use .xcconfig files?  If so, you can point your configuration (Debug or Release) to the appropriate .xcconfig file by selecting the project in the hierarchy view in xcode, then selecting the project (instead of a target) in the dropdown across the top.  You should see a section called 'Configurations' where you can select the file.

In order to ensure that it's not coming from the xcode project file, you need to delete the entries there.  This will be in any section labeled `buildSettings`.  You can debug by selecting a target and 'Build Settings' and then switching to 'levels' view (vs 'combinded') which will show where each setting is coming from.

See the documentation and links on this project for more details:

https://github.com/distiller/DIConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

You can edit through here

**Target** > **Edit Scheme**
[image]

P.S: Mine using xcode 5